# Mongoose auto increment multiple models Initialize connection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the plugin
[mongoose-auto-increment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment)
and it is working fine.

In the description we have to use it like this

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
 
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");
 
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
 
var bookSchema = new Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    publishDate: Date
});
 
bookSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Book');
var Book = connection.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

I have multiple models where i need to auto increment fields

**Do i have to initialize in each model** the below line

```
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/myDatabase");
```

in each model file (where i need increment function)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I share the solution i implemented myself

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost/mydatabase");
autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);

exports.mongoose = mongoose;
exports.Schema = Schema;
exports.autoIncrement = autoIncrement;
```

and for the schema file

```js
var mong = require('./db');
var Schema = mong.mongoose.Schema;
var autoIncrement = mong.autoIncrement;
 
var bookSchema = new Schema({
    author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' },
    title: String,
    genre: String,
    publishDate: Date
});
 
bookSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Book');
module.exports = mong.mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```